# Service in binded Jar doesn't come up without "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"

Tags: android, xamarin, android-manifest

I have an App that uses a Service that I've added by a Bindable Jar.

**Current state:**
this Jar has an own Manifest (see below), when I don't touch anything on this Manifest everything works as it should.

**Problem:**
This Jar lets on Deployment to Device always its launer AppIcon on Device.
So my App leaves finaly two launcher icons, the one desired and the other from the Jar.
My Approach was to **delete follow Part** from Manifest:

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ScanDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Doing this the App Crashed on BootUp with Error: BootReceiver not found ...
Deleting the next few Lines:

```
<receiver android:name="com.company.scandemo.BootReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

caused started correctly on bootUp, but the Service didn't come up on *BOOT_COMPLETED*, when I start the App via Launcher icon everything worked.

**Wished Behaviour:**
I want the Main App to leave only one launch Icon and startup correctly on Boot

Here is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.scandemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="2.2" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".ScanDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.company.scandemo.FloatingService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.company.scandemo.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: please try set the icon in the both manifests the same: android:icon="YOUR ICON"

Comment: that can't help, since the App and the binded Jar have their own places "drawable Folder" to save their resources

Comment: can't you replace that by your icon ?

Comment: I could, but then i just would have two launcher with the same Icon. But I want only the have the only One launcher icon. The binded Jar has no dependencies to the App itself.